# Best way to upgrade a site from Bootstrap 4.0.0 to latest 4.3.1?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, upgrade

I want to upgrade a Bootstrap 4 html/css website from Bootstrap 4.0.0 to the latest version (currently 4.3.1).  I have googled this and only see instructions for upgrading from 3.x.x to 4.x.x.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This can't be rocket surgery.  Do you just copy over the files into the folders and see what breaks?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the lack of resources provided. However unlike the migration from 3.x.x to 4.x.x, there isn't any loss of component here. But you will see some nasty changes, that will just break things. I would suggest going through the examples for version 4.0.0 and then cross referencing them with the ones for 4.3.1 .This will not solve your problems but it will definitely point you in the right direction.

Comment: Christian below says "no breaking changes".  What do you think I should be looking for?

Answer (score -1):

You found nothing, because there is not much to say (There should be no breaking changes).

So you simple need to update (replace) the library files (CSS, JS, Probably Fonts).

Note: In current days we use Package Managers like [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) and install our frameworks as Packages. In case of NPM, you can [find bootstrap here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap).

Comment: Himanshu above says "nasty changes that will break things".  Confusing!

Comment: I suggest, simple try it out. When you have specific problems, ask about them.